# “To tell” in German

Tags: word-usage, difference, verb, synonym

I’ve come across the following verbs:

> *erzählen*, *verraten*, and *sagen*,

which all mean ‘to tell’.

What’s the difference between them?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stsack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works. Good question; +1.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, *tell* has a few differing meanings and depending on what you're going to express, you need to translate differently.

*Erzählen* is *to tell a story* or *to tell a joke*, *verraten* is *to tell a secret*, and *sagen* is simply *to say* as in *die Wahrheit sagen (to tell the truth)*.

Actually, this is general reference and all these information are given in dictionaries. For example, consult the [Pons dictionary](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=tell&l=deen&in=&lf=de&cid=).

For the sake of completeness, here are how to use the three translations you mentioned:

- jemandem etwas erzählen: Ich habe dir die Geschichte gestern schon erzählt. (I've already told you the story yesterday.)
- jemandem etwas verraten: Ich werde dir nicht verraten, wie ich den Zaubertrick gemacht habe. (I won't tell you how I did this magic trick.)
- jemandem etwas sagen: Ich sage dir wirklich die Wahrheit. (I am really telling you the truth.)

Answer (score 17):

*Verraten* is in the sense of a secret.

> Tell me your secret.
>   Verrate mir dein Geheimnis.

*Erzählen* is mostly in the sense of a story. Also, it could be used for a request to be told what happened.

> Tell me the story.
>   Erzähl mir die Geschichte.
>
> Tell me what happend.
>   Erzähl mir was passiert ist.

*Sagen* describes more or less the rest. It is a more neutral term.

> Tell me when it's over.
>   Sag mir wenn es vorbei ist.

Nearly everywhere where you could use *verraten* or *erzählen* you could use *sagen*. The following would be valid also.

> Sag mir dein Geheimnis.
>   Sag mir was passiert ist.

But with the story, it is **not** correct.

> Sag mir die Geschichte. (**not** correct)

In the case of a story or tale it has to be *erzählen*.

Comment: Seems that erzählen will translate well as 'to relate' : e.g. To relate a story.